# why my host add automaticlly add secure flag to cookie?

Tags: php, cookies, header

I wrote a program that set a cookie. it work well in http mode, but when I use https protocol, header of cookie add automatically add secure flag to it.

> set-cookie: val=is; expires=Sun, 16-Feb-2025 07:26:50 GMT; Max-Age=90000; path=/; secure

my code is:

```
<?php
header('Set-Cookie: val=is; expires=Sun, 16-Feb-2025 07:26:50 GMT; Max-Age=90000; path=/');
```

What makes this happen?

Comment: That's the way https protocol works, trying to secure every request.

Comment: but i read that without secure flag, the cookie in http and https is accessible. also some browser can not load my website in https mode and i don't know why.